# Rails 4 Css undefined method `empty?' for 10:Sass::Script::Number

Tags: sass, ruby-on-rails-4

I just started a Rails 4 pet project this month, and I kept running in to a weird problem,

```
undefined method `empty?' for 10:Sass::Script::Number
   (in /home/mickey/workspace/punchclock/app/assets/stylesheets/punchclock_bootstrap.css.scss)
```

This happened whenever I modify my CSS file, I need to commit, push, delete the folder, clone, setup then the problem would go away = . I haven't encounter this problem working with Rails 3, I think this only happens to my laptop, which is running with a Virtual Box installation of Ubuntu.

Anybody encouter this too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bad installation of rails, I imploded rvm and reinstalled everything, and solved my issue. = )